# How to automatically replace for with while loops in python?

Tags: python, refactoring, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to create apply transformations to python code.

For example I want to be able to transform this:

```
for i in range(10):
   print(i)
```

into this:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
   print(i)
   i += 1
```

are there any tools that can achieve this?

I tried using the python ast library.

Comment: Some IDEs may have tools to do this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The `for` loop is usually the preferred way.

Comment: Hm, I do not know any IDE able to do this... For creating semantically equivalent versions of a program to extend a machine learning dataset

Comment: I know that JetBrains IDEs (e.g. PyCharm) have lots of code refactoring operations, although I don't know if it has this particular one.

Answer (score 1):

Those loops you showed aren't really equivalent. Python's for loop is in fact a for-each loop, range isn't true for-i loop like in other languages.

Let's take your example:

```py
for i in range(10): 
    print(i) 

i = 0 
while i < 10: 
    print(i) 
    i += 1
```

And see what happens in the for vs in the while when we actually add something that modifies i:

```py
for i in range(10): 
    i = 0
    print(i)
```

This will just print 0 ten times. Because we just get next element from the range object each time, we don't care that we overwrote i inside the loop

But if we did it in the `while` example, we'd get an infinite loop:

```py
i = 0 
while i < 10: 
    i = 0
    print(i) 
    i += 1
```

As you can see, what you made isn't really an equivalent.

So how to do the `while` loop from `for` (for-each) loops? You gotta understand iterables and iterators in Python. For-each takes each element from the iterable by making an iterator and calling `next` on it. Loop stops when StopIteration is raised.

Quick example:

```py
for elem in iterable:
    ...

# is something along the lines of
my_iter = iter(iterable)
try:
    while elem := next(my_iter):
        ...
except StopIteration:
    pass # no more elements
```

That should probably work if any nested loops also have their own except (so you don't exit from the outer one early!).

There are some explanations about the iterators, iterables, and how the python's for loop works on Real Python website - https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/

Comment: Are there any situations where they're not equivalent except when the loop body modifies the interation variable? That's a rare exception and the hypothetical tool could detect it.

Comment: @Barmar it depends what we are talking about. The loop body could advance the iterator, e.g `next(iterator)` where you've done `for x in iterator`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed, I've written `for line in file:` loops that have calls to `file.readline()` in the body. But changing these to `while` loops doesn't change the semantics.

Comment: Another problematic case is when the body of the loop contains a `continue` statement.   If the increment is placed last in the converted code, it will not get executed in that case (whereas an actual for-loop would do it properly).

Answer (score 1):

*blah blah blah **you should probably not change for-loops into while-loops** blah blah **more error-prone** blah blah **less readable** blah blah **about the same performance** blah blah blah.*

#### Are there any tools that can achieve this?

Yes, I know at least `libcst` can do this, it's really efficient for massive code refactoring:

- documentation [here](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- tutorial [here](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).

#### Code example

Here is a bare-bone example, hard-coded: you'll need to change things to make this more generic, but it gives the great picture.

```py
from libcst import (
    IndentedBlock, SimpleStatementLine, Name, FlattenSentinel, RemovalSentinel,
    BaseStatement, For, While, Comparison, ComparisonTarget, LessThan,
    Integer, AugAssign, AddAssign, CSTTransformer, parse_module, Assign, AssignTarget)


class LoopUpdater(CSTTransformer):
    def leave_For(
            self, original_node: For, updated_node: For
    ) -> BaseStatement | FlattenSentinel[BaseStatement] | RemovalSentinel:
        """Transform a for-loop into a hardcoded while-loop"""

        # Hardcoded iteration init (i = 0)
        init_i = Assign(targets=[AssignTarget(target=Name(value='i'))],
                        value=Integer(value='0'))

        # Hardcoded while condition (i < 10)
        i_under_10 = Comparison(left=Name(value='i'),
                                comparisons=[ComparisonTarget(
                                    operator=LessThan(),
                                    comparator=Integer(value='10'))])

        # Hardcoded iteration block (i += 1)
        increment_i = SimpleStatementLine(body=[
            AugAssign(target=Name(value='i'),
                      operator=AddAssign(),
                      value=Integer(value='1'))])

        return FlattenSentinel([
            SimpleStatementLine(body=[init_i]),
            While(test=i_under_10,
                  body=IndentedBlock(
                      body=list(updated_node.body.body) + [increment_i]))
        ])


test = r'''
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
'''

cst = parse_module(test)
updated_cst = cst.visit(LoopUpdater())

print(updated_cst.code)
```

Output:

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I used libcst to solve my problem. I also added checks to not change the loop if it might contain one of those problematic cases described in the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could to convert it using an iterator and the next() function.

For example:

```
iLoop = iter(range(10))
while True:
   i = next(iLoop,iLoop) 
   if i is iLoop: break
   ...
```

This would cover most cases but still would have an issue with the `else:` part of the for-loop.  A for-loop with an `else:` component would only execute the else part if the iteration was NOT broken by a `break`.  In this case, the loop would always be broken by a break.

Alternatively, you could write a small class that manages the iterating and current value:

```
class ForLoop:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.idata = iter(data)
        self._value = None
        
    @property
    def value(self): return self._value

    def __call__(self):
        self._value = next(self.idata,self)
        return self._value is not self
```

This will have all the characteristics and behaviour of a for loop including processing of `continue`, `break`, (re)assignment of the `i` variable and not absorbing any exceptions.

output:

```
iLoop = ForLoop(range(10))
while iLoop():
    i = iLoop.value
    print(i)

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

While this was an interesting thought experiment, it seems a bit futile to change one construct for another, less efficient, one.  Perhaps you could post your objective in doing this transformation in your question.